how to link movement with keyboard controls and pointerlock controls for a first person experience with R3F and Rapier?
so I have an index.jsx file defining my keyboard controls and has my pointer lock controls in.
root.render(
    <StrictMode>
        <Leva collapsed />
        <KeyboardControls
            map={ [
                { name: 'forward', keys: [ 'ArrowUp', 'KeyW' ] },
                { name: 'backward', keys: [ 'ArrowDown', 'KeyS' ] },
                { name: 'leftward', keys: [ 'ArrowLeft', 'KeyA' ] },
                { name: 'rightward', keys: [ 'ArrowRight',  'KeyD' ] },
                { name: 'jump', keys: [ 'Space' ] },
            ]   }
            >       
                <Canvas
                    shadows
                    camera={ {
                        fov: 45,
                        near: 0.1,
                        far:    20000000,
                        position: [     - 150, 3, 6 ]
                    } }
                >
                    <Physics 
                        debug={true}>  
                        <Experience />
                    </Physics> 
                <PointerLockControls/>        
                </Canvas>
        </KeyboardControls>    
    </StrictMode>
)

I cant work out how to link them so the forward movement is sort of pushing the camera along with it and left and right and so on like in an fps shooter.
const Player = () => {
    const { rapier, world } = useRapier();
    const rapierWorld = world; // Correct usage

    const ref = useRef(null);
    const [subscribeKeys, getKeys] = useKeyboardControls();
    
    ?!?!?!!?!? WHAT GOES HERE TO LINK THEM? ?!?!?!?!

    return (
        <RigidBody
            ref={ref}
            position={[0, 1, 0]}
            restitution={0.3}
            friction={0.7}
            linearDamping={0.5}
            angularDamping={0.5}
            colliders="hull"
        >
            <mesh castShadow>
                <icosahedronGeometry args={[0.3, 1]} />
                <meshStandardMaterial flatShading color="limegreen" />
            </mesh>
        </RigidBody>
    );
}

export default Player;

I have made it in the past so I had pointer controls and WASD but they were not connected so if the mouse turned the camera the 'forward' then came backward
